# Switch to narrower rims on a hybrid?

Tags: tire, rims

Following up on my [original wheel issues question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/13245/213), I went to see my local cycling store to tell them about my problem.

I want to change rims and would like to have them support tires from 23 to 28mm. My frame is a [hybrid one](http://www.trekbikes.com/us/en/bikes/town/fitness/fx/7_2_fx/#/us/en/model/details?url=us/en/bikes/town/fitness/fx/7_2_fx), perhaps a bit on the MTB-side, so I originally have a 17mm wide rim (supporting 25-38mm tires).

I did not have a lot of time but the guy said there were no rims to fit my needs and that at best I would be able to comfortably run on were 25mm tires...

Was there some kind of misunderstanding between us or was he making a valid point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would think that concerning the rim there must have been a misunderstanding. You should be able to run a narrower rim, and simply adjust the brakes, unless there is a reach issue with the brakes.

It's possible that the hubs on your wheels are MTB style, which have a different width than road hubs. You would still have the option of buying new rims and having them laced to your existing hubs if you are serious about running narrower tires.

That said - as a long time recreational rider/commuter - I don't see much benefit from running any tires narrower than 28-25 unless you are planning on racing (which isn't really a target use for your bike).

Comment: Thanks! I plan to keep my hub and have the new rim laced. So the 130mm vs. 135mm should not be an issue right? As for the tire width: I run 28mm now, and it's great! I prefer the feeling over my old 35 mm so no way of me coming back to 35+, so would love to keep my options open and be able to fit comfortably 25mm tires, have 23mm as an (fast) option, 28mm as a standard possibility and keep 32mm as a wide-confortable backup option. This whole range should be possible with 15mm wide rims (instead of my current 17mm) according to Sheldon: http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html#ETRTO

Comment: @tisek: Why not just sell the hybrid and buy a road bike?  That seems to be what you're aiming for.

Comment: You are making a valid point but the reasons are that I like the flat handlebar, because I am not giving up my rear rack nor my pannier, nor my mudguards. I just feel that my daily 11 miles daily commute, on smooth clean pavement requires no comfort-tires just mostly going for the performance.

Comment: If you are going so far as to re-lace new rims to the hubs, your LBS doing the job should be able to adjust the brakes for you.

Comment: Yep, and change the pads who show some wear already after 2 weeks (that is what pushed me over the edge and go for the new rim... the old one is definitely dead).